# Product of entire function with function with a pole

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

So far my attempt has been to try proving that it is neither a pole nor essential. For the pole case, I wrote $h$ in the form $f(z)/|z|^n$ and then considered the product, but I don't know how to rigorously justify that $|z|^{\frac{1}{3}}$ won't "drag down" the function as $z\rightarrow0$. For essential, I think I should try to show that the image is not dense in $\mathbb{C}$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Lookup Riemann's theorem on removable singularities.

Comment: @MartinR I know the theorem, but I don't know how to show that f is necessarily bounded. Why should this follow from the assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M= \sup_{0<|z|<1}|z|^{1/3}|h(z)|$. Then
$$
 |z h(z)| = |z|^{2/3} \cdot |z|^{1/3}|h(z)| \le |z|^{2/3} \cdot M
$$
so that $\lim_{z\to 0} z h(z) = 0$. Now [Riemann's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann%27s_theorem) on removable singularities implies that $h$ has a removable singularity at the origin.

---

*Regarding your approach:* Consider the function $f(z) = z h(z)$. Then $f$ is bounded in a neighborhood of the origin, so that $f$ has a removable singularity there, which implies that $h(z) = f(z)/z$ also has a removable singularity or a pole.

It remains to exclude the case that $h$ has a pole at the origin: If $h$ has a pole with multiplicity $p \ge 1$ then
$$
 h(z) = \frac{A}{z^p} (1+ O(z))
$$
for $z \to 0$ with some non-zero constant $A$. But then
$$
|z|^{1/3}|h(z)| = \frac{|A|}{|z|^{p-1/3}}(1+O(z))
$$
is not bounded near the origin.

Comment: Ah, I guess I wasn't familiar with all the formulations of the theorem. Only the one that says to show h is bounded.

Comment: @Marble: I have added another argument, which is more complicated, but (perhaps) is what you were thinking of.